# I need to run Initialize code one time in junit before test - java

Tags: java, junit, annotations

I need to run Initialize code one time in junit before test - java.

if we choose
@Before

It will run before on every test void.

```
Object me;
```

`public void InstalizeTestClass()}`

```
me = configReader.read();
```

`}`

```
@Test
public void SumTest(){

}
```

when i used @BeforeClass found exeption
java.lang.Exception: Method InstalizemockTest() should be static

```
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.validatePublicVoid(FrameworkMethod.java:93)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.validatePublicVoidNoArg(FrameworkMethod.java:74)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validatePublicVoidNoArgMethods(ParentRunner.java:155)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.collectInitializationErrors(ParentRunner.java:125)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:124)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:416)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:65)
at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:10)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Comment: `@BeforeClass`. Or, if it doesn't throw a checked exception, just do it on the field.

Comment: An important point here is that `Object me` has to be static if you want it to persist between test cases, because a new instance of the test class is created per test case.

Comment: "when i used @BeforeClass found exeption java.lang.Exception: Method InstalizemockTest() should be static" and even tells you how to fix it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `@BeforeClass` annotation for this:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void myLogic() {
  // Code that needs to run once
}
```

Comment: No it's not working.because variable in scope was not there

Comment: @Chamikara see my comment "An important point ..." on the question.